# Best practices to save models that are related with a foreign key

Tags: php, database, foreign-key-relationship, yii

There is a scenario like this, I have a model `Project` and this project has a gallery of `Image`s. So:

```
Project HAS_MANY Image
Image BELONGS_TO Project -> Foreign key: project_id
```

In a form I want to be able to save project information and multiple images all together. The problem is that how can I get the `project_id` since the model `Project` has a id that is auto-increment and I have no access to it before saving the model.

One way that I thought about is to dummy save the model in the begining then after user submits the form updating it. But it seems very nasty!

What are the best practices to save models with HAS_MANY and BELONGS_TO relationships in the same form?

Comment: `dummy save the model in the begining` it's ok, set state of dummy models if user do not upload any images, and you need to delete dummy projects

Comment: This is a problem when you have some mandatory fields... I don't want to make the user to save some part of the form first, and then let him update the rest...

Comment: can you not save the images if `$project->save()` returns true, and if any images fail to upload add that as an error to the project model?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the best solution is the extension [activerecord-relation-behavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/activerecord-relation-behavior/). The extension will be handling all the HAS_MANY and MANY_MANY relations.

Since it's a behaviors, it'll be handling the part where you need the id of the parent model to assign it to the childrens. So instead of doing

```
//save to get the id
if($project->save()) {
    foreach($images as $image) {
        $image->project_id = $project->id;
        if(!$image->save()) {
            //Handle the errors        
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have simply to do:

```
$project->images = $images;
if($project->save()) {
    //do what you have to do (redirection, render, ...)
}
```

Comment: It will be works if she will be used standart uploads, if Masha will use smth like xuploadform when dummy save have to used.

Comment: don't forget to check if the project first saves and the save the images.

Comment: yeah you're right i wanted to make it simple, will edit my example

Comment: with the extension the dummy save will be performed, but you won't have to worry about it. After you called $project->save() you'll have just to redirect the user or show the appropriate view